# Eclipse-RCPTT If condition Implementation

Tags: if-statement, eclipse-rcptt

Can some briefly explain how "If" condition works in Eclipse-RCPTT script or link where can I get information regarding this?

Comment: You should only ask concrete problems on StackOverflow. This question shows no search effort on your side, I recommend you to remove it.

Comment: I tried but the thing is that I am not able to the requirement as I need it.
The thing that I need to catch if there is any window popup and need to do something on that popup window.
Can you help with me?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from your comment:

" I need to catch if there is any window popup and need to do something on that popup window"

That's too general to answer, with "try" you can write code that reacts if a window is missing:

```
try {
    get-window "My Dialog" | get-button OK | click
} -catch {
    // Window was missing, let's try something else
}
```

There's no generic "switch" or "if" window title matches, instead a write a separate case for each situation.